# Azure webApp adding custom domains with special chars

Tags: azure-web-app-service, domain-name, azure-dns

I have in the past added domains like (non-existing, but containing the national letters ):

- lækkertdomainname.dk
- grøndomainname.dk
- blåsomainname.dk

Azure won't let me enter them anymore.They seem to have changed the UI.

I have also tried using the puny-code. I can enter it, but looking up the asuid then fails, even though a service like https://digwebinterface.com/ will report both:

- asuid.lækkertdomainname.dk TXT "123THEASUSID123123123123"
- asuid.xn--lkkertdomainname-uob.dk TXT "123THEASUSID123123123123"

I can't think of anything else to try. Help.